# calling a jsp from a servlet

Tags: jsp, servlets, redirect, forward

I'm calling a JSP, `displayItems.jsp` from a servlet, `DataPortal.java`. First I tried to do this using the `RequestDispatcher` like this,

```
String url = "/displayItems.jsp";
ServletContext context = getServletContext();
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = context.getRequestDispatcher(toDo);
dispatcher.forward(req, res);
```

well... the control did go to the JSP page, however it printed the entire contents of the JSP file (including tags and everything) instead of displaying as a webpage. Next I tried to achieve this by using `response.sendRedirect(url);` and this time it gives me an empty page. What am I doing wrong here? The JSP is like this,

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
    <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />        
<meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css" />
<script src="http://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/files/jquery-1.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
    <body>
    <div>i am in display category</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is solved. This is how: I had a DispatchServlet calling the DataPortal which in turn was calling the displayItems.jsp. The reason dispatcher.forward was not working in DataPortal was because i was doing dispatcher.include in DispatchServlet to call the DataPortal. When i changed this to forward, things started working. So thank you guys, for your response.

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
RequestDispatcher RequetsDispatcherObj =request.getRequestDispatcher("/displayItems.jsp");
RequetsDispatcherObj.forward(request, response);
```

Comment: I've tried that too. It did not work. It prints the contents of the file rather than bringing up a webpage.

Comment: content of file mean? are you getting the servlet  values?

Comment: yes I am getting the servlet values. Well.. the problem is solved. This is how: I had a DispatchServlet calling the DataPortal which in turn was calling the displayItems.jsp. The reason dispatcher.forward was not working in DataPortal was because i was doing dispatcher.include in DispatchServlet to call the DataPortal. When i changed this to forward, things started working. SO thank you guys, for your response.

Answer (score 0):

What about `dispatcher.include(req, res)`? This is if you want to call a jsp from servlet.

Answer (score 0):

forward will just forward the request to next page where as sendRedirect will first come back to the page where its been generated and the redirect to next page

Comment: Oh ok. That means i shouldn't be trying with sendRedirect. But I still don't get why forward isn't working for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getRequestDispatcher("URL to jsp");
dispatcher.forward(request, response);
```

Answer (score 0):

RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getRequestDispatcher(request.getContextPath()+"/");
dispatcher.forward(request, response);

Answer (score 0):

There is an easier way to call a .JSP File from a Servlet.

You do not even need to create   tags in web.xml.

Just type:

1. Create a Servlet with a doGet method;
2. Call a method sendRedirect;

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
{**response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");**}

index.jsp should be your .JSP file name. Please note you do not type / prior indicating .JSP file name!